# Symfony 3 - How to pass data from controller to type

Tags: types, doctrine-orm, symfony

What I want to do is, to pass data from the controller of my bundle

```
$departmentChoices = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MasterDataBundle:Department')->findAll();
```

to my Typeclass:

```
class DivisionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $this->traitChoices = $options['trait_choices'];

        $builder
            ->add( 'Name', TextType::class )

            ->add('Standorte', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $this->traitChoices['name']
            ])
            ->add( 'Groups', TextType::class )
            ->add( 'Chief', TextType::class )
            ->add( 'Description', TextareaType::class )
            ->add( 'save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Standort Erstellen',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ),
            ) )
            ->add( 'delete', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Eingaben löschen',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
                ),
            ) );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'trait_choices' => null,
        ));
    }

}
```

When I dump `$this->traitChoices` I get all fetched objects. I need their names as choices. What am I doing wrong ?

Kind regards for your help ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) instead, which will fetch your departments for you:

```
->add('Standorte', EntityType::class, [
    // query choices from this entity
    'class' => 'MasterDataBundle:Department',
    // use the User.username property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'name'
])
```

or, if you want to keep your `ChoiceType`, `choices` should be your object list, and you use the `choice_label` option to set the label:

```
->add('Standorte', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => $this->traitChoices,
    'choice_label' => function ($value, $key, $index) {
        return $value['name'];
    }
])
```

Comment: Hello Olivier, 

thank you very much for your fast and efficient help! Both solutions are working for me. The first one is more "symfony" than the second one. I hope I will be able to give something back sometimes!

Kind regards...